# Adding Libraries to Netbeans Raspberry Pi

Tags: c++, linux, netbeans, raspbian

I am pretty noob at c++ and raspberry pi so any help would be appreciated.
I currently have Raspberry Pi with a RF24 connected and an Arduino with a RF24 and magnetometer also connected separately.  I have used a RF24Mesh example code to get the arduino to connect to the mesh and to send data.  Right now I want to make my own mesh file so that I can send data to my webserver but I need to add the RF24 libraries and the curl libraries to the IDE I am using on my desktop.  This is where I am lost on what to do.  I have the directories downloaded but how do I add them to IDE?  I was attempting to do this with Code::Blocks but had problems compiling because of compatibility issues so now I am using NetBeans to compile directly on my raspberry pi.